How to dynamically display static text region in Oracle APEX based on whether currently selected person has an active pending request?

I have "textfield with autocomplete" (P2_EE) returning a list of values as "lastname, firstname [emp #]".
On P2_EE change, I parse out the emp #, pull data, and populate some readonly page items.
I want to conditionally display a static text block that warns if the selected person already has a pending request in the app.  The block would need to hide or show as appropriate for any selection change in P2_EE.
I've tried doing this as an on-change dynamic action (running right after the on-change event listed above) which also has a server-side condition of "rows returned" based on sql (which checks if the emp # already has a pending request).  Then I do a simple Show action on the static text region when true.

Unfortunately, the text block never displays.
I'd be grateful for any thoughts/suggestions.
Thank you.

The reason the text block never displays is the server-side condition. That is evaluated at page rendering time and never re-evaluated again.
There are a couple of ways of solving this but the easiest is a creating a helper page item "P2_EE_SHOW_WARNING".
In the on-change dynamic action, add an action of type "Execute Server-side code" to set this item to Y or N (make sure that "Items to return" has "P2_EE_SHOW_WARNING"). (This action does what the Server-side Condition in your question is supposed to do).
Add a show action with client-side condition
apex.items.P2_EE_SHOW_WARNING.getValue() === 'Y' and a hide action with apex.items.P2_EE_SHOW_WARNING.getValue() === 'N' .
Let me know how this goes I can put together an example if needed.

Worked like a charm, Koen.  Thank you.  I guess I'm confused about the point of allowing a "rows returned" check in a dynamic action if it's not going to be dynamic (i.e. checked when the action happens).  But that's a question for Oracle.  Thanks again!!
